# Can I assign a letter to or hide stuff in the System Reserved partition safely?

Tags: windows-10, system-reserved-partition

EDIT: You know what?? I found out that the System Reserved partition is just as fragile as the system32 folder; do ANYTHING AT ALL to it and Windows becomes unbootable. I'll just shrink my E: partition and make a new partition with no drive letter.

---

I was thinking of both:

1. Assigning a drive letter to the System Reserved partition and/or
2. hiding secret stuff in it.

However, it's a critical system partition I'm talking about here. I know how to assign and re-assign drive letters [it's through the Disk Management], but I want to know if either or both of these things are safe to do or if they're just as dangerous as deleting the System32 folder. For reference, I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Not a good idea...

Comment: if you want to "hide" data, encrypt it. Anything less is pointless. Don't use System Reserved for anything. its call "System Reserved" for a reason. Its Reserved for the System.

Comment: Hiding things is not pointless - it is on the same level with door locks. Keeps honest people honest and private people private. But yes, SR is not the best place... Also, hiding an encrypted container somewhere sensible is the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want a partition that is out of view to the casual observer, you can create such a partition (and not assign a drive letter) as long as you have (or make, by shrinking another partition - all the usual cautions about resizing partitions apply!) free space left on a drive.

The System Reserved partition seems to be mostly there to hold boot loader components etc - damaging anything could make the system unbootable. Notably, instructions do exist on how to install a working Windows 7 without SR, with the boot loader files going to the system partition. I would approach with caution here, scenarios like a C: partition large enough to cross any legacy LBA or partition size limit could yield annoying surprises.